# Find line-meshgrid intersections without sorting?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, graphics, geometry

I am trying to find line-meshgrid intersections without sorting. Here is the figure:

[image]

**Known:**

- The two intersection points on the boundary: (x0 y0) and (xN,yN)
  are known.
- The position of each meshgrid line is known. [-R R] is the span of the meshgrid.
- The meshgrid is centered at Cartesian origin symmetrically.

**What I want:**

I'd like to get an array of all intersections in either ascending or descending order, based on the distance from each point to either the starting point (x0,y0), or the end point (xN,yN).

**For example:**

`(x0 y0), (x1,y1),(x2,y2)..., (xN,yN):` acceptable

`(xN yN), (xN-1,yN-1),(xN-2,yN-2)..., (x0,y0)`: acceptable.

`(x0 y0), (x3,y3),(x1,y1)..., (xN,yN)`: not acceptable.

**What I am stuck at:**

I understand I can at least calculate each intersection with a for loop, but I don't know how to save the intersections with the order motioned above without sorting (bubble ex.). Say, I start from (x0,y0), then which way to go to find my first intersection? Particularly, should I go along x direction, or should I go along y direction, so that I can hit my first intersection? And how about the next move to my second one?

I figure is there anyway to do it in a "natural" geometry way? The slope (assuming the line is not vertical) of the line is known, and the meshgrid is known, so is there any trick we can play here? Thanks a lot

**In addition:**

What if I'd like to do all the intersections in parallel? Say, in CUDA.

Comment: At each step, there are only two possibilities. Intersection with either x or y grid line. So just check for the nearest horizontal and vertical lines and proceed the point.

Comment: @user1990169 Thanks a lot. But if I want to parallelize the computation, say, doing all the intersections on multiple threads. How do I do the strategy you mentioned? Thanks.

Comment: @Ono First divide the line into segments, put each thread to working out the intersections over a segment, and then put the segments in order as a final step.

Comment: I see. I think both of you guys are very helpful. I like to combine both of your answer together. Cannot figure out how you guys post your answers......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a unit tile size, the coordinates of the intersections are found at `x = i` and `y = j` respectively, for increasing indexes.

Using the parametric line equation `x = X + t U, y = Y + t V`, the intersections occur at `t = (i - X) / U` and `t = (j - Y) / V`, which we rewrite `U V t = V (i - X)`, `U V t = U (j - Y)`, for convenience.

These two sequences are naturally sorted, they follow two arithmetic progressions of common differences `V` and `U` and initial indexes `i = Ceil(X)`, `j = Ceil(Y)`. Then what you need to do is a merge of the two sequences.

```
# Initialize
i= Ceil(X), j= Ceil(Y)
Tx= V (i - X), Ty= U (j - Y)

# Loop until the final point
while i < XX and j < YY:
    # Move to the next intersection
    if Tx + V < Ty + U:
      Increment i, Tx+= V
    elif Tx + V > Ty + U:
      Increment j, Ty+= U
    else:
      Increment both i and j, Tx+= V, Ty+= U
```

The second coordinate of an intersection is found from the relevant value of `T`.

Comment: @Yevs Daoust: Am I understanding correctly: When you increment i, or j, it is not just i++ or j++, instead i, and j should follow the ray direction (from incident to exit), so it could be either ++ or --?

Comment: Looks like filling a 2D area from x and y direction respectively. The x and y direction compete against each other to decide which one (x or y) fills.

Comment: I think it is a great idea. However, shouldn't it consider the slope of the ray? For example: if the slope <0 and assuming ray travels from top to bottom, then x increases, whereas y decreases, and the area increasing in y direction is always less than that in x direction , because the area accumulate in y direction is always negative.

Comment: Perhaps the condition in the while loop should be applied with abs(), for example if Tx + V < Ty + U: -> if abs(Tx + V) < abs(Ty + U): ?

Comment: Yep, the principle algorithm was written for the first quadrant, with positive increments. You need to adapt for the three others.

Comment: It's probably possible to work with absolute values as regards the evolution of T, and signed values when computing X and Y - this is a micro-optimization issue. Cheers !